# Best Practice - DRY violation Rails <-> JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, dry

I've implemented a star rating system for a web project.

The number of stars is calculated in the rails backend and rendered with the view.
Now I also implemented dynamic rating via ajax. Thus I need to dynamically update the star rating.

In order to achieve this I've simply duplicated the rails code and re-implemented it in JavaScript. Although this solution works I'm not really happy with it because it seems like a big violation of the DRY principle.

What's the best practice in this matter? Calculate all star ratings via JavaScript?

I'm glad for possible solutions.

Answer (score 2):

You could make an AJAX get request for the action that calculates this rating. In this action you could see if the request was an AJAX one, and then just return the value calculated, instead of rendering the related view.

I assume you are familiar with rendering JSON, with the `respond_to` and `request.xhr?` methods and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

If you are already doing an Ajax call ("I also implemented dynamic rating via ajax"), why not just do the calculation before you send the response, and add the result to the response?

Comment: I could do this of course. The problems are the following:
- The "rate" link has no direct connection to the displayed rating in the frontend, at the moment I'm searching for the rating after the ajax callback via a jquery selector.
- The rating itself consists of three numbers: The total rating count, number of full stars and number of half stars to represent the rating visually.

What i could to is just render the star icons via javascript according to the return result numbers.

Would this be an appropriate solution? (With all stars icons rendered via js, none via rails backend)

Answer (score 0):

I decived to go with the following solution:

- calculate the rating in the rails backend (no. of stars full and empty)
- write a view partial to render the star rating
- include the partial in the "normal" views
- return the partial as ajax response for the rate function, the current rating is replaced by the response via jQuery

I think I can ignore the small html overhead the little partial has - it's sleaker than returning Json and formatting it with JavaScript.